# Finding the query causing the missing index DMVs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, index, dmv

How can I find the query causing the missing index DMVs suggesting to create a particular index?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer: you can't with 100% accuracy.

Long answer: you can query the plan cache to identify plans with missing index warnings and compare the results with what you find in sys.dm_db_missing_index_* DMVs. [Here's a script that you could use to query the plan cache](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/digging-into-the-sql-plan-cache-finding-missing-indexes/). If the plan doesn't get cached or gets pushed out the cache for any reason, you won't find any matches, so we're back to the short answer.

To be 100% sure, you would have to trace the workload and capture the plans with missing indexes. It's not lightweight and it's not trivial. [Here's a script to do that](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/092e840e-7229-46af-93f8-60deeac76b64/can-sql-profiler-give-you-the-missing-index-information?forum=transactsql). With a small effort it could be ported to Extended Events.

Answer (score 3):

Querying the plan cache to look for the indexes involved in the calculation of finding missing indexes DMV's can be looked from below pasted link:

https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/finding-what-queries-in-the-plan-cache-use-a-specific-index/

and refer to link as well for more explanation on the same

http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/dbadmin/sql-server-dba-tip-missing-index-dmv/